# Как воспроизвести звук так, чтобы он не перебивал другой звук?

Tags: c#, winforms, аудио, mediaplayer

Есть такой код (условный):

```
SoundPlayer back = new SoundPlayer(...);
SoundPlayer click0 = new SoundPlayer(...);
SoundPlayer click1 = new SoundPlayer(...);
void MainFormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    back.PlayLooping();
}
void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    click0.Play();
}
void Button2Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    click1.Play();
}
```

После запуска программы, начинает воспроизводиться фоновый звук (back), но стоит только нажать на любую кнопку, как фоновый звук останавливается и воспроизводится другой (собственно back0 или back1).
Скажите пожалуйста, есть ли способ воспроизводить несколько звуков сразу. Неважно будет ли это с использованием SoundPlayer'а или сторонней библиотеки.
Заранее спасибо

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285294/play-multiple-sounds-using-soundplayer

Comment: Библиотеку NAudio поизучайте. Она доступна в NuGet.